# how to load data from sharedpreferences?

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

this is my code of save data:

```
private void Save_it() {
        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(SAVED_HOUR_1, selected_hour_1);
        editor.putInt(SAVED_MINUTE_1, selected_minute_1);
        editor.putInt(SAVED_VOLUME_1, selected_volume_1);
        editor.putString(SAVED_TIME_TEXT_1, Name_Time_1);
        editor.putString(SAVED_VOLUME_TEXT_1, Name_Volume_1);
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_TIME_1, checktime_1);
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_VOLUME_1, checkvolume_1);
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_1, checkset_1);
        editor.putInt(SAVED_HOUR_2, selected_hour_2);
        editor.putInt(SAVED_MINUTE_2, selected_minute_2);
        editor.putInt(SAVED_VOLUME_2, selected_volume_2);
        editor.putString(SAVED_TIME_TEXT_2, Name_Time_2);
        editor.putString(SAVED_VOLUME_TEXT_2, Name_Volume_2);
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_TIME_2, checktime_2);
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_VOLUME_2, checkvolume_2);
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_2, checkset_2);
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_ENABLED_2, checkenabled_2);
        editor.apply();
}
```

And this is my code of load data:

```
private void Load_it() {
        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String Saved_Time_Text_1 = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_TIME_TEXT_1, Name_Time_1);
        set_time_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_time_1);
        set_time_1.setText(Saved_Time_Text_1);
        String Saved_Volume_Text_1 = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_VOLUME_TEXT_1, Name_Volume_1);
        set_volume_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_volume_1);
        set_volume_1.setText(Saved_Volume_Text_1);
        selected_hour_1 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_HOUR_1, 0);
        selected_minute_1 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_MINUTE_1, 0);
        selected_volume_1 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_VOLUME_1, 0);
        checktime_1 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_TIME_1, false);
        checkvolume_1 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_VOLUME_1, false);
        checkset_1 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_1, false);
        String Saved_Time_Text_2 = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_TIME_TEXT_2, Name_Time_2);
        set_time_2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_time_2);
        set_time_2.setText(Saved_Time_Text_2);
        String Saved_Volume_Text_2 = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_VOLUME_TEXT_2, Name_Volume_2);
        set_volume_2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_volume_2);
        set_volume_2.setText(Saved_Volume_Text_2);
        selected_hour_2 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_HOUR_2, 0);
        selected_minute_2 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_MINUTE_2, 0);
        selected_volume_2 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_VOLUME_2, 0);
        checktime_2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_TIME_2, false);
        checkvolume_2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_VOLUME_2, false);
        checkset_2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_2, false);
        checkenabled_2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_ENABLED_2, false);
}
```

But load doesn't work right. I use data for setText in textView and set boolean and integer variables. I guess the problem in Load code: I use it not right. What wrong? Help!!
EDIT here: goo.gl/fhIxdv

Comment: Which part of your code is not working right? I mean entire your load data is not working? or only few lines. Please mention.

Comment: What a mess, sorry I can not look on this code, please send it to some code review.

Comment: @Jerry, answer the question..

Comment: @ChaitanyaAtkuri, My data is loaded incorrectly

Comment: @ChaitanyaAtkuri, open the link, I've put in there my code which I use

Comment: If possible send the sample android project of this, so that we will be able to understand which are wrong and which are right

Comment: @ChaitanyaAtkuri I soldev my problem, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this post, Also take a look at my answer; I have showed a proper way of storing and getting preferences. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339982/save-number-input-from-edittext-into-sharedpreferences/38340272#38340272)

Try something like

```
private String DEFAULT_SP_KEY = "default_sp_key";
private void Save_it(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(DEFAULT_SP_KEY, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(SAVED_HOUR_1, selected_hour_1);
    editor.putInt(SAVED_MINUTE_1, selected_minute_1);
    editor.putInt(SAVED_VOLUME_1, selected_volume_1);
    editor.putString(SAVED_TIME_TEXT_1, Name_Time_1);
    editor.putString(SAVED_VOLUME_TEXT_1, Name_Volume_1);
    editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_TIME_1, checktime_1);
    editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_VOLUME_1, checkvolume_1);
    editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_1, checkset_1);
    editor.putInt(SAVED_HOUR_2, selected_hour_2);
    editor.putInt(SAVED_MINUTE_2, selected_minute_2);
    editor.putInt(SAVED_VOLUME_2, selected_volume_2);
    editor.putString(SAVED_TIME_TEXT_2, Name_Time_2);
    editor.putString(SAVED_VOLUME_TEXT_2, Name_Volume_2);
    editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_TIME_2, checktime_2);
    editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_VOLUME_2, checkvolume_2);
    editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_2, checkset_2);
    editor.putBoolean(CHECK_IF_ENABLED_2, checkenabled_2);
    editor.apply();
}

private void Load_it(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(DEFAULT_SP_KEY, 0);
    String Saved_Time_Text_1 = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_TIME_TEXT_1, Name_Time_1);
    set_time_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_time_1);
    set_time_1.setText(Saved_Time_Text_1);
    String Saved_Volume_Text_1 = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_VOLUME_TEXT_1, Name_Volume_1);
    set_volume_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_volume_1);
    set_volume_1.setText(Saved_Volume_Text_1);
    selected_hour_1 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_HOUR_1, 0);
    selected_minute_1 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_MINUTE_1, 0);
    selected_volume_1 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_VOLUME_1, 0);
    checktime_1 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_TIME_1, false);
    checkvolume_1 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_VOLUME_1, false);
    checkset_1 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_1, false);
    String Saved_Time_Text_2 = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_TIME_TEXT_2, Name_Time_2);
    set_time_2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_time_2);
    set_time_2.setText(Saved_Time_Text_2);
    String Saved_Volume_Text_2 = sharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_VOLUME_TEXT_2, Name_Volume_2);
    set_volume_2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_volume_2);
    set_volume_2.setText(Saved_Volume_Text_2);
    selected_hour_2 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_HOUR_2, 0);
    selected_minute_2 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_MINUTE_2, 0);
    selected_volume_2 = sharedPreferences.getInt(SAVED_VOLUME_2, 0);
    checktime_2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_TIME_2, false);
    checkvolume_2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_VOLUME_2, false);
    checkset_2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_SET_2, false);
    checkenabled_2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_IF_ENABLED_2, false);
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14856214)

Comment: yeah, I think this should work, but I don't need it now.. I need to edit my code to make it work... Can you tell me something about my code, maybe you see there something wrong?

Comment: @Eldelshell I Agree with you.

Comment: @JerryLetehen, Please see my edits, and please add a key to your Shared prefs.

Comment: @Salvatory Baya nothing changed. Still show me wrong variables. I will edit my question to add something of code.. look